# Are there any recommendations for optimal placement of the computer monitor within a room?

Tags: ergonomics, eye-strain

I have a vague memory of reading something from the Joel Spolsky's blogs regarding the need to have something distant to look at to avoid eye strain. Are there any studies or recommendations suggesting against the placement of a monitor directly in front of the wall (having you face the wall, with the monitor in between).

I have lately been starting to experience eye strain and think that the placement of the monitor might be a factor. I have also started the habit of taking a break every 20 minutes (http://lifehacker.com/5591835/reduce-computer+caused-eye-strain-with-the-20+20+20-rule), but it isn't helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that placing the computer screen in front of a wall could be a problem in this case: if you want to look at something distant, just look at something distant in another part of the room for a while.

That said, there are some general guidelines to follow if you want to reduce eye strain:

> - Keep the viewing surface of your monitor clean
> - Position the monitor directly in front of the user with the top of the screen in line with or slightly below eye level
> - Position monitor 20-26" from the user
> - Tilt the top of the monitor back 10-20 degrees
> - Position monitor perpendicular to windows and away from direct    lighting to reduce glare

Source: [Computer Workstation Ergonomics | Hall Health Primary Care Clinic](http://depts.washington.edu/hhpccweb/content/clinics/family-health/computer-workstation-ergonomics)

Comment: I would think that if the monitor is placed, say, in the middle of the room, every time you look slightly off the monitor your depth of vision has to switch from near-sighted to far-sighted, which gives your eyes some sort of workout every now and then.

Comment: A doctor some time ago told me that it is enough to do this, say, once every hour or so, to let the eyes rest for a while and train them to look further away. I don't know if doing it very often can help even more.